# Drupal compute field devel display

Tags: 7, entities

I have created a compute field in Drupal 7 in which I want all the fields above to display through devel something like `dpm($all field);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) { // check if you're on a node page & get node object.
  dpm($node); // dump the node object which contains all fields.
}
```

Comment: updated answer, actually there is no need to load the node object since menu_get_object already gets it.